# Batch File to delete folders who don't have a specific word

Tags: batch-file

I have a Movie folder that contains the following structure:

```
C:\Movies\Movie Title 1
C:\Movies\Movie Title 2
C:\Movies\Movie Title 3 xyz
C:\Movies\Movie Title 4 xyz
C:\Movies\Movie Title 5
C:\Movies\Movie Title 6 xyz
C:\Movies\Movie Title 7.avi
C:\Movies\Movie Title 8.mp4
```

What I'm looking for, is a batch file that I can run over a task scheduler, to delete all the folders (and is content), that don't have the word `xyz`, and in addition also other file types in Movies folder, e.g.:

```
C:\Movies\Movie Title 7.avi
C:\Movies\Movie Title 8.mp4
```

Thus, as a result of the batch file execution, I would only have:

```
C:\Movies\Movie Title 3 xyz
C:\Movies\Movie Title 4 xyz
C:\Movies\Movie Title 6 xyz
```

What I have so far is this code:

```
set folder="C:\Movies\"
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir *.* /q || del *.* /q)
```

But this, only delete files in the folder movies, doesn't delete folders who don't have the specific word as I mentioned above.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: there are a few ways, but you need to at least show what you have tried before I can really post an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use many methods.. for one, you could use `findstr` and run both `del` and `rmdir` on the files, without having to check what they are and simply redirect to `nul`.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b C:\Movies\ ^| findstr /vi "xyz"') do (
  del /Q "%%i">nul
  rmdir /Q/S "%%i">nul
)
```

Feel free to read up on the above commands from `cmd.exe`

- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`

Comment: If it worked, you should throw Gerhard a bone by accepting this as the accepted answer ;)